# Sending data from server to iPhone with NSURLConnection using php

Tags: php, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection, echo

I have a server running with a sql server database, and I am able to send data from it to my iPhone. Here is the code I use:

PHP on server

```
<?php
$headers = getallheaders();
$length = $headers['Content-Length'];
$input = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$json = json_decode(fread($input, $length));
fclose($input);
$search = $json->{'search'};
$value = $json->{'value'};

$serverName = "SOMEONE-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM testtable
WHERE $search='$value'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt ) ) {
    $arr = array('firstname' => $row['firstname'], 'lastname' => $row['lastname']);
echo json_encode($arr);
}

?>
```

My Objective-C code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *urlString = @"http://someipaddress";
    NSString *post = @"{\"search\":\"lastname\",\"value\":\"mylastname\"}";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"%i", ++_count);
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}
```

This gives me the output:

```
2013-11-12 22:58:03.743 httppostrequests[25708:70b] 1

2013-11-12 22:58:03.745 httppostrequests[25708:70b] {"firstname":"Thomas    ","lastname":"mylastname"}{"firstname":"person    ","lastname":"mylastname"}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to change the servercode so that didRecieveData gets called more than once so the data would be send in bits instead of being send as one big text. I am just curious on how this works because when I make a simple request to "http://www.google.com" the didRecieveData gets called four times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveData%3a) the following is said about didRecieveData `Sent as a connection loads data incrementally`. It also says `This method provides the only way for an asynchronous delegate to retrieve the loaded data. It is the responsibility of the delegate to retain or copy this data as it is delivered.`. In essence this means that `didRecieveData` is called everytime some block of data is available, the reason google get's chunked up is most likely because the data block has some size which the response from google exceeds, but you data does not.

EDIT: I am not sure, but I think using [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) will affect this. So if you set a low chunk size it's possible that it could work as you wanted.